# Unwanted- White space in mobile view- why is it happen?

Tags: html, css, overflow

thanks to anyone who considers helping me.

When I am resizing my website, there is a white space that is being created.
[The white space I refer to, circled in orange.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7hm6.jpg)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWVN)

I don't know why it happens, and when I use:

overflow: hidden; / overflow-x: hidden;
It fixes the issue.
[using overflow, and it is fixed!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dur4d.jpg)

Can someone help me understand why using overflow: hidden **fix the issue**?
And also, why is this happen in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

overflow - means that something (in this case one of your html items) is so to say bigger than its container and therefore it overflows or spills out. by making it "hidden" you hide it and therefore only the part of your item which fits to its parent container is visible

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. 

1. How to spot that one html items?

2. How to fix it?

Basically, you are saying that one item is bigger than the container, and because the deafult is overflow:visible, so this is why I am getting the white space- because its bigger, so it has to be visible.

Comment: there is a lot of different approaches out there. consider drawing borders for your elements when you make a layout of a page and you will see who is out of the flow

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could share some of your code that way we could build off of it and see more clearly what is happening.

That being said, the large white space is due to the image for `CBS CNN` being too wide as you can see in your first image. In the second image, you make overflow hidden and the `CBS CNN` is cut in half to fix your issue. You need to change the way you style that image for mobile view.